# Vary the fill scale when using facet_wrap and geom_tile together

Tags: r, ggplot2, tile, facet

When using function `geom_tile` and `facet_wrap` together in ggplot2, how to set different limits of the aesthetic `fill`, as the option `scales` which can be set to be `free/free_y/free_x` in `facet_wrap`?

The following is an example to show the problem. For different `type` in data.frame `df`, the range of `z` could be so different. If we use the same limits of aesthetic `fill`, some panle, which one the `z` part have very small value, would be hard to see the details.

```
pp <- function (n,r=4) {
    x <- seq(-r*pi, r*pi, len=n)
    df <- expand.grid(x=x, y=x)
    df$r <- sqrt(df$x^2 + df$y^2)
    df$z <- cos(df$r^2)*exp(-df$r/6)
    df
}
tmp <- pp(20)
tmp$type <- rep(1:4,each=nrow(tmp)/4)
tmp$z <- tmp$z*(10^(tmp$type))
ggplot(tmp,aes(x,y))+geom_tile(aes(fill=z))+facet_wrap(~type,scales="free")
```

Comment: Not at computer, but have you tried the `shrink` argument?

Comment: you would need a different legend for each facet, that's not really compatible with the ggplot2 framework. You could easily produce independent plots and arrange them together though.

Answer (score 10):

I know this is an old issue, but I recently had the same problem and came up with this solution that I wanted to share. The trick is to collect the datasets needed for the individual `geom_tile()` plots in a nested dataframe using `nest()` from `tidyr` and then use `map2()` function from the `purrr` package and a wrapper function to create the individual plots:

```
library(tidyverse)

pp <- function (n,r=4) {
  x <- seq(-r*pi, r*pi, len=n)
  df <- expand.grid(x=x, y=x)
  df$r <- sqrt(df$x^2 + df$y^2)
  df$z <- cos(df$r^2)*exp(-df$r/6)
  df
}
tmp <- pp(20)
tmp$type <- rep(1:4,each=nrow(tmp)/4)
tmp$z <- tmp$z*(10^(tmp$type))

plot_func <- function(df, name) {
  ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = z)) +
    geom_tile() +
    scale_fill_continuous(name = name)
}

nested_tmp <- tmp %>% 
  group_by(type) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(plots = map2(data, type, plot_func)) 

gridExtra::grid.arrange(grobs = nested_tmp$plots)
```

[image: Grid-plot of maps with different color scale]

The nested dataframe contains two list-columns, which contain the datasets and plots:

```
> nested_tmp
# A tibble: 4 × 3
     type               data    plots
    <int>             <list>   <list>
  1     1 <tibble [100 × 4]> <S3: gg>
  2     2 <tibble [100 × 4]> <S3: gg>
  3     3 <tibble [100 × 4]> <S3: gg>
  4     4 <tibble [100 × 4]> <S3: gg>
```

From here it is very easy to modify `plot_func()` to fine-tune the plots.

Comment: This is awesome!

Comment: +1 This is very cool. You can pipe directly into `grid.arrange` if you use `grid.arrange(grobs = .$plots)`

Answer (score 3):

One way to solve this problem is to standardize the fill variable, so that the scale is similar for all facets.

```
library(dplyr)
tmp1 <- group_by(tmp,type) # grouping the data by type
tmp2 <- mutate(tmp1, z1 = (z-mean(z))/sd(z)) #groupwise standardization 
ggplot(tmp2,aes(x,y))+geom_tile(aes(fill=z1))+facet_wrap(~type,scales="free")
```

I wish there were anything like `fill=std(z)` so that I don't have to manually standardize.